# Is there any Jmeter plugin that can be used to "test a regular expression" for Respose Headers

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I tried using View Results tree listener's RegExp Tester mode . But I am not able to view response headers. Also When i changed value of the drop down to Text. The response header doesn't appear here as well.
Is there any other listener which shows the response headers and also enables the user to test regular expression?
Or Is there any setting to enable viewing of Response headers in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Response headers can be viewed in the view results tree listener in the Sampler result tab [image]

About testing the response with regular expression again the regular expression post processor has the ability to extract data from the response headers [image]

Comment: I am not able to see response header in the View Result Tree. Though I am able to see the request header in it. Also I wanted to check if my regular expression is correct or not, We usually use RegEx tester of view results tree listener, But as i said I am not able to see the response header so I can't use it.

Comment: Are you recording your scenario with HTTP/S test script recorder ? If yes there is a check right next (on the right side) of the grouping drop-down option, which is "Capture HTTP headers" make sure this is checked. Are your requests passing/failing? Try making the request with Fiddler or some other sniffer tool is there header in the response?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you should be using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to see the values of extracted variables.

However you can use a form of "hack" to add headers to response so you could use RegExp Tester.

1. Add [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request which header(s) you want to correlate
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   String original_response = new String (data);
   String headers = prev.getResponseHeaders();
   String new_response = headers + original_response;
   prev.setResponseData(new_response.getBytes());
   ```
3. Above code will extract response headers and put it **before** original response data so it will be visible in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and you will be able to test your Regular Expressions

   [image: Headers in response body]

W.R.T. Beanshell code:

- `data` - is java [byte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) array which contains parent Sampler response
- `prev` - stands for [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html), see JavaDoc for available methods and fields.

Also check out [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using JMeter and Java API from Beanshell test elements in your JMeter test.

---

**Don't forget to disable or remove the Beanshell PostProcessor once you sort out your correlation issue**.